# TinyMCE wont strip ALL inline-styles (all attributes) and empty tags

Tags: javascript, tinymce

No matter what I do, what docs I read, what custom scripts I try, I cannot get TinyMCE to remove ALL inline styles and delete empty tags.

1. If you CTRL+A the text from this [Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-pa0kPYcI3S9b-MUE4YTmsUtyKHV67TO7qwLbICVXdU/edit?usp=sharing)
2. And paste it into this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/goldencarers/pen/ZEXZPqY)
3. And then click the "Code" button on TinyMCE, you'll always have this stuff

```html
<h1>&nbsp;</h1>
<li style="font-weight: 400;" aria-level="1"><span style="font-weight: 400;">Lorem Ipsum</span></li>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

I want it to do what html-cleaner.com does upon `paste`, which leaves you with perfectly clean HTML. If you copy the TinyMCE html result into that site, you'll get this result:

```html
<h1><strong>Title</strong></h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
<h3><strong>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</strong></h3>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.&nbsp;</p>
<ul>
<li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy tex</li>
<li>he industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</li>
<li>when an unknown printer took&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
<p>Tt to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into ele</p>
<h3><strong>Simply dummy text of the&nbsp;</strong></h3>
<p>Readable English. Many desktop publishing packages</p>
<ul>
<li>Lorem</li>
<li>Ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This feels like I'm getting closer: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/2807

Comment: `invalid_elements:""` and `invalid_styles:""` are also a step in the right direction, but for whatever reason `invalid_elements:"*[*]"` doesn't work, nor does something more explicit like `li[aria-level]`